# Change vertex shape conditionally

Tags: r, igraph

I can change the color of the vertices conditionally:

```
V(net)$color <- ifelse(V(net)$type == "bla", "darkblue", "orange")
```

However, when I try to do the same for shapes, nothing changes:

```
V(net)$vertex.shape <- ifelse(V(net)$type == "bla", "circle", "square")
```

Thanks.

PS:

Example:

```
nodes <- data.frame(name = c("1", "2", "3"), type = c("a", "b", "b"))
edges <- data.frame(from = c("1", "1"), to = c("2", "3"))

net <- graph_from_data_frame(edges, directed=FALSE, vertices=nodes)
V(net)$size <- 2
V(net)$color <- ifelse(V(net)$type == "a", "darkblue", "orange")
V(net)$vertex.shape <- ifelse(V(net)$type == "a", "circle", "square")
plot(net)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `?igraph.plotting` there are several ways to add parameters. You are using the second way which "is to assign vertex, edge and graph attributes to the graph". The next sentence in the help is relevant: "*These attributes have no prefix*".

Thus for this method, you just need to use

```
V(net)$shape <- ifelse(V(net)$type == "a", "circle", "square")
```